# Get Applications Associated with file extension

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am looking for a way, in Cocoa, to get all of the applications associated with a file extension or a similar procedure to what the Finder does with it's `Open With >` menu.

I have looked into launch services, and I think that's the right path possibly, but there appear to be missing applications. I don't think it's quite right.

For example, I have both **Sublime Text** and **Visual Studio Code** installed. Both appear in the `Open With >` menu in the finder for a `.html` document. When I try this in Cocoa, both are excluded:

```
var handlers = LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType("public.html", kLSRolesEditor).takeUnretainedValue()
var identifiers: [String] = handlers as! [String]

for id in identifiers {
    var path = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier(id)
    var name = NSFileManager.defaultManager().displayNameAtPath(path!)
    println(name)
}
```

I have tried the following content types with the same excluded results:

```
public.html
public.source-code
public.text
public.plain-text
```

None of those result in a list of bundle identifiers which contain **Sublime Text** or **Visual Studio Code**.

I have also tried all of those content type variations changing the role to `kLSRolesAll` again with results not matching my expectations.

I can only assume there must be some other way to retrieve a list of applications for a given file extension that is not Launch Services related that I am simply missing in my Googling around.

I have also attempted this with objective-c with the following:

```
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:@"file:///path/to/an/html/file/index.html"];
CFArrayRef urls = LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url, kLSRolesEditor);
NSArray *appUrls = CFBridgingRelease(urls);
NSLog(@"%li", appUrls.count); // 0
```

Again also with `kLSRolesEditor` and `kLSRolesAll`

Comment: You're creating your `NSURL` wrong. You're using `-initFileURLWithPath:` but not supplying a path. You're supplying a URL string, which is not a path. For me, `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL()` gives me the same list as the Finder (although the Finder sorts it). Also, you should use `takeRetainedValue()` with `LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType()` because it returns a retained value, as indicated by "Copy" in its name.

Comment: The fileUrl adjustment did the trick for `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL`. If I may be so bold as to ask a follow up question: Is there a way to get the information that `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL` provides without having a file on the file system AKA just using the extension? If not, your comment is the answer. I would just package a file in my resource bundle as a work around.

Comment: I would have expected `LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType()` to do it. I'm not sure why it's not giving the same result as `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL()` for a file of the same type. In theory, I suppose some apps may claim file extensions using the `CFBundleTypeExtensions` Info.plist key rather than `LSItemContentTypes`. In that case, maybe Launch Services doesn't recognize them as handling a given content type but would recognize them as handling a file with the given file extension.